# AJAX request with laravel 5.2 error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have this ajax request in `home.blade.php` :

```
function send(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')},
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('add_action') }}",
        data: {name: $("#name").val(), niceness: $("#niceness").val(), _token: "{{ Session::token() }}"}

    });

}
```

in the controller I have this postAction:

```
public function postInsertNiceAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'     => 'required|alpha|unique:nice_actions',
        'niceness' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);

    $action = new  NiceAction();
    $action->name = ucfirst(strtolower($request['name']));
    $action->niceness = $request['niceness'];
    $action->save();
    $actions = NiceAction:: all();

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json();
    }

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

I added this meta tag:

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

so when I run this I got this error :

> jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/do/add_action 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

I tried to change the version of the jQuery file but it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated!

I'm new to Laravel.

Thank you

Comment: Read: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/422-unprocessable-entity-error-when-submitting-form-with-ajax

Comment: Try to remove `_token` from ajax post data `data:{name: $("#name").val(), niceness: $("#niceness").val()}` you already setting in header

Comment: still the same error @user2486

Comment: unprocessable entity means there's something wrong with the data you're trying to post, like validation errors

Comment: This simply shows validation error. can you dd($request) before the $this->validate() and check what it shows?

Comment: A 422 error is when the validation fails. If you look at the response in the network tab of your browser it should show you what part of your validation is failing. Alternatively, you can add the following to your `$.ajax` object:  `error: function () {console.log(r.responseJSON.errors);}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function send(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('add_action') }}",
        data: { name: $("#name").val(), niceness: $("#niceness").val() },
    });
```